# Django template static images with absolute path

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to create this `meta` tag, which requires an absolute URL:

```
<meta name="name" content="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{% static 'app/images/my.png' %}">
```

This prints:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000//static/app/images/my.png

I need to print:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app/images/my.png

How can I remove this "/"?

My static_root:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

Comment: Could you post what you static route configuration looks like?

Comment: Why do you need {{ request.build_absolute_uri }}? Can't you just do: content="{% static 'app/images/my.png' %}" ?

Comment: That is for a `<meta>`. I need the complete path. And the domain can change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `slice` filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/)

```
<meta name="name" 
      content="{{ request.build_absolute_uri | slice:":-1" }}{% static 'app/images/my.png' %}">
```

This will take the trailing `/` off of the `build_absolute_uri` result.

Comment: This will not properly work on the non-homepage URLs. E.g. if you're on `http://example.com/news/article-slug/` then your static image URL will be `http://example.com/news/article-slug/app/images/my.png`